# Zoom image script not working

Tags: javascript, zooming

I'm trying to get [this](http://nivozoom.dev7studios.com/) script to work but am having some trouble.

This is my [website](http://india.thefalljourney.com/2011/11/27/test-post/).

I followed the instructions on the script's website and did this:

1. Added the reference for the script to `head`.
2. Added `<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function() {$('body').nivoZoom();
   });</script>` right after the script reference in the head. Should I call the function elsewhere?
3. Wrapped the smaller image inside `<a>` tags and added the class of `nivoZoom`. All the links for images are working.

The problem with my website is that the script isn't working. Instead, if the smaller image is clicked it just leads to the large image address and doesn't zoom as it's suppose to.

**UPDATE:**

Here's my whole `<head>`, <strike>I don't see where I load jQuery for the second time</strike> <strike>OK, I see that it loads but I can't find where the code is</strike>:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src='/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/js/example.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://india.thefalljourney.com/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/js/nivo-zoom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/js/jquery.nivo.zoom.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('body').nivoZoom();
});
</script>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

<?php if (is_search()) { ?>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
<?php } ?>

<title>
       <?php
          if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
             single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
          elseif (is_archive()) {
             wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
          elseif (is_search()) {
             echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
          elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
             wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
          elseif (is_404()) {
             echo 'Not Found - '; }
          if (is_home()) {
             bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
          else {
              bloginfo('name'); }
          if ($paged>1) {
             echo ' - page '. $paged; }
       ?>
</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://india.thefalljourney.com/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/favicon.png?force=1">
<!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://india.thefalljourney.com/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/favicon_blue.png?force=1"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://india.thefalljourney.com/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/favicon_flag_india.png?force=1"> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Found the additional loading, it was in the `functions.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your page, you load jQuery + nivoZoom:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/js/jquery.nivo.zoom.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

A few lines below, you load jQuery again, causing the previously made extensions to the jQuery framework to be undone:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
```

You should include the nivo zoom script AFTER loading jQuery:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/js/jquery.nivo.zoom.pack.js"></script>
```

Another note: Your CSS file is missing. Make sure that you also upload it.